# The Search Service Application crawl DB default has grown to 60GB

Tags: search, database

Our Search Service Application was installed but never configured with rules.  Our default Search Service Application Crawl DB has grown to 60GB.  We attempted to create a new Crawl Database and reassign component.  Point of doing this to delete the default Crawl Database to free up some space.  In the process of creating the new database and assigning component and then deleting the default database the process failed because it ran out of space.
We were able to add another 10GB of space.  We are wondering what the best plan of action is to end up with a properly sized Crawl db with rules that excludes specific sites.

Do we need to repoint the component to the Default crawl db, delete the new db then create new db, reassign component to it and then delete the default crawl db and then unpaused the crawl?

Comment: Will you please provide an estimate of the volume of content you are indexing (types of content/document types, number of files, total size, average item/document size)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can lose the search configuration and crawl data, which is sounds like you can, delete the Search Service Application and choose the option to delete the associated databases.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Estimate performance and capacity requirements for SharePoint Server 2010 Search whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/F/0/7F069D0B-B6BD-4692-868B-E8555BB72445/SearchforSPServer2010CapacityPlanningDoc.docx) (docx warning) contains detailed capacity calculations. See pages 50-55 (physical pages, not the page numbers reported within the document itself) under the heading **Calculate storage sizing**.

It's detailed. You'll need a pen and paper (or excel).